# Adb working perfectly in terminal but in android studio it only shows initialzing adb

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

After I re installed my os my adb isnt working, i tried through terminal it works but not in android studio. when i run an application it only shows initialzing adb. th

Comment: Try enabling ADB .... Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration

Answer (score 0):

When you run `ADB` from the command line, it starts an adb-server.
If you start this from an admin account, and open Android Studio without admin permissions, then it cannot kill the existing ADB server.

So to answer: Make sure you kill the existing ADB server from the command line, and then open up Android Studio.